# How to create a dmg/pkg to install an Excel add-in created using Yeoman generator on Mac

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, yeoman-generator, dmg

I have an excel add-in created using the Yeoman generator and I'd like to distribute this as a downloadable dmg/pkg for others to use on Mac.

How can I create a dmg/pkg file to easily install the add-in on Excel Mac?

I have tried using this [dmg tool](https://github.com/create-dmg/create-dmg) to create the dmg but it doesn't open or install anything. Do I need to add a specific script to install the add-in? If so, how would that script work and is there any examples available to follow?